# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in def

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to run the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root=TK()
root.title("Password Generator")
root.geometry("640x480")
label=Label(root)
array_3D=[[['1','2','3','4','5','6'],["Head","Tail"],["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]]

def new_password():
    random_no_1=random.randint(0,5)
    random_no_2=random.randint(0,1)
    random_no_3=random.randint(0,7)
    letter_1=str(array_3D[0][0][random_no_1])
    letter_2=str(array_3D[0][1][random_no_2])
    letter_3=str(array_3D[0][2][random_no_3])
    label["text"]=letter_1+letter_2+letter_3
btn=Button(root,text="Generate 'Weak' Password",command=new_password)
btn.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
label.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.6,anchor=CENTER)
root.mainloop()
```

It gives me the following error:
File "main.py", line 9
def new_password():
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What is the problem?

Tried changing Indentation, but Nothing Happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a closing bracket for `array_3D`

Try
`array_3D=[[['1','2','3','4','5','6'],["Head","Tail"],["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]]]`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot a closing ] bracket from the list of list of lists before.

```
array_3D=[[['1','2','3','4','5','6'],["Head","Tail"],["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]]
```

3 open only 2 close at the end.